# Make this automatic

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make this carrousel slide through slides by itself?

```
var main = function() {

    $('.arrow-next').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var nextDot = currentDot.next();

        if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
            nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
            nextDot = $('.dot').first();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });


    $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {
        var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
        var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

        var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
        var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

        if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
            prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
            prevDot = $('.dot').last();
        }

        currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
        prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

        currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
        prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
    });

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Hope you can help,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use setInterval and trigger("click") and the carousel will be "clicked" every seconds.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $(".arrow-next").trigger("click");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Another question, I have 4 dots you can click for the carrousel. Is it possible when you click those. The function stops and goes to like 10 seconds instead of 3?

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. That is my fault though. You can't click on the dots, but you can click on the arrows, so arrow-next and arrow-prev. Can you make that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInverval function.

The setInterval take a function (the one that will trigger next slides in your case) and a time in milliseconds, this is a the delay between every call to the function.

stInterval return a value that you must stored in memory and pass to clearInterval when your object is destroyed

Documentation : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp